# Where can I get a list of all inbuilt parameters in Jenkins parameterized build?

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-cli

I am just using Jenkins for less than 2 days so my question might be pretty amateurish. I want to remote trigger a Jenkins parameterized build (I just want to explore a little bit, no serious job). I am not using any custom parameters but only inbuilt parameters like 'delay' and 'quietPeriod'. So far I searched for a complete list of inbuilt parameters for Jenkins but have found none. Can anyone please help me or am I searching for wrong thing here?

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins, there is no such term used as the built-in parameter. But from what you provided in the description of your concern it seems that you are looking for the environment variable for Jenkins. Please follow below link where the available environment variable is documented which is automatically generated by the system.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables

There are additional environment variables which inherit in every build of your environment can be reviewed at ***Manage Jenkins -> System information***